# My FTTC Network Connection Device is flashing red?

Tags: router

My FTTC Network Connection Device is making a ticking sound and interlocked circles symbol one to the left of the blue power light is flashing red?

Comment: There's no standard for this. Look up the owner's manual for your particular model online.

Comment: Speak to your ISP if your internet is not working or if you have a question about their device.